# Suggestion on how to fix CORS error in Lightning Out

Tags: cors, salesforce, sessionid

I have below vf page in org A.

Created an aura app- PublicApp and LWC- cardCmp in org B. Also, I have added entry of org A's domain URL in CORS setting in org B.

When I run below VF in org A then I get error: CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Any pointers on how to solve this error?

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" cache="false" standardStylesheets="false">
<script src="https://mydev-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/lightning/lightning.out.js"></script> 
<div id="LightningComponentid" />    
 
<script>
$Lightning.use("c:PublicApp", 
    function() {
        $Lightning.createComponent("c:cardCmp",
          {},
          "LightningComponentid",
          function(cmp) {
             console.log('LWC Componenet added in VF page');
          });
    },
   'https://mydev-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com',
   '00D5g000A2P4I!AQMlaPEytZTygXiqUxrmv9jkAWjpNat80TIM1iGEz_SaPbLU98YDPoj7j7LLNSbwAf0kVLV4anERkvU6.Uc.QX'
    
    );
</script>
</apex:page>
```

Please note last 2 parameters of $Lightning.use() are - URL for the Lightning domain on org B's Salesforce instance and session id of admin user of org B respectively.
I have added them hardcoded way just for testing purpose. Later I will make it dynamic.

Comment: Hi, I am hitting the same issue, Did you manage to resolve it ?